# Sortable - scroll page

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

what do you think about this code? Can you do it better or have better idea how scroll page if customer drag element?

This is my variable which are defined outside the function.

```
var Ymax = $( document ).height();
var Xmax = $( document ).width();
var Xright = window.innerWidth;
var Xleft = 0
var Ytop = 0
var Ybottom = window.innerHeight;
```

this is function sortable:

```
sort: function(e) {         
        if(event.pageY > Ybottom-50 && Ybottom <= Ymax){
            window.scrollBy(0,10)
            Ybottom+=10
            Ytop+=10
        }
        if(event.pageY < Ytop+50 && Ytop >= 10){
            window.scrollBy(0,-10)
            Ybottom-=10
            Ytop-=10
        }
        if(event.pageX > Xright-50 && Xright <= Xmax){
            window.scrollBy(10,0)
            Xright+=10
            Xleft+=10
        }
        if(event.pageX < Xleft+50 && Xleft >= 10){
            window.scrollBy(-10,0)
            Xright-=10
            Xleft-=10
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you encountering any specific errors with this code? Is it not operating the way that you expect?

Comment: if page don't load in top:0 or left:0, I must wait little time when ytop or xleft slow jump to current position

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read: What types of questions should I avoid asking? https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Also this is already a feature of Sortable: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-scroll

Comment: Twisty, sory this is my first post but thanks for support. I read this doc about sortable but it did not work with me. Ok I find good, and work 100% method and I think you can close the topic. Thanks